# using explode() to split strings and set variables possible?

Tags: php

Is it possible to have a string like this:

```
|
details==Here are some details
|
facebook_url==therweerw
|
random_word==blah blah
|
```

and get this:

```
$details = "Here are some details";
$facebook_url = "therweerw";
$random_word = "blah blah";
```

The main point is I'd like to parse this in a way that the string to the left of the "==" delimiter will become a variable with the string to the right as it's string.  I'd like to not have to hard-code those variables.

Comment: explode won't be a good option, at least not by it self. also you have a closing quote missing in details

Comment: I would love to see this working :-). To understand this, are you trying to generate any PHP code? Or you want to have this as a part of a code which does something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$str = '|
details==Here are some details
|
facebook_url==therweerw
|
random_word==blah blah
|';

preg_match_all('~^(\w+)==(.*)$~m', $str, $matches);

foreach ($matches[1] as $i => $name) {
    $$name = $matches[2][$i];
}

var_dump($details, $facebook_url, $random_word);
```

And running sample: http://ideone.com/Vns7Y

Comment: I mean, what more could you want?

Comment: @Doug Owings: uhm, what? I want million dollars ;-)

Comment: Just saying: it took you four minutes to post a working sample. Impressive.

Comment: @Doug Owings: hehe, that wasn't so obvious for me from your first phrase ;-))

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `explode()` plus [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) to do this.

Comment: How can `extract()` help with this?

Comment: `extract()` is another way of doing the equivalent of `$$x = y;` en masse when you have an associative array where the keys are x's and the values are y's.

Comment: I know what `extract()` does. I'm asking how can `extract()` be useful, when `explode()` creates an array with numeric indexes. Do you really suggest to use loop to create an array with variable names as keys and then use `extract()` instead of creating variables directly in the same loop?

Comment: No? I agree that using variable variables is probably the more straightforward way to do it, and would never argue differently; `extract()` was simply the first thing that came to mind, and there wasn't much of a point adding the other when someone had already added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use `preg_match_all()` for this, but here's example with `explode()`:

```
$str = "|
details==Here are some details
|
facebook_url==therweerw
|
random_word==blah blah
|";
$str = str_replace("\r", '', $str);
$str = trim($str, "|\r\n");
foreach ( explode("\n|\n", $str) as $line ) {
    $line = trim($line);
    list($varName, $varValue) = explode('==', $line);
    ${$varName} = $varValue;
}
var_dump($details, $facebook_url, $random_word);
```

Output:

```
string 'Here are some details' (length=21)
string 'therweerw' (length=9)
string 'blah blah' (length=9)
```